# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when passing a parameter in dispatch_async in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I pass a variable to another method. when accessing this property app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

```
   in class1: 
  CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer;
  @implementation class1
     - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
        pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           predictions = [dTFG runX:pixelBuffer orientation: UIDeviceOrientationPortrait CardRect: _vwRect];

       }
     }
   } 

    in class2:
    - (NSArray*) runX:(CVPixelBufferRef) pixelBuffer orientation: (UIDeviceOrientation) orientation CardRect:(CGRect) CardRect {
       CFRetain(pixelBuffer);  // Error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x800000060)
    }
```

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x800000060)

When I commented  dispatch_async, crash not happened.

According to another answer, this error is (probably) because of released object. but why is it released in this situation but without dispatch_async, it is not released.

Comment: Hi, did you checked the value of pixelBuffer while you are passing it to CFRetain(pixelBuffer).

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan Thanks. I cannot see its preview in this situation.

Comment: The documentation says CFRetain requires a non-null value. You are passing a null value which causes a runtime error. The code you showed does not update the value of pixelBuffer anywhere. So most likely it's null and causing the crash.

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan I don't know why it is null, I think the object is released. but why it is released in dispatch way but not without it.

Comment: can you show the code where are you setting pixelBuffer?

Comment: So is `captureOutput` called on a background thread?

Comment: @matt Yes the codes I write in it should be run in background.

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan I added that line to the codes.

Comment: Can you check and verify that pixelBuffer has a valid value when you are passing to the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CVImageBufferRef` returned by [`CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/1489236-cmsamplebuffergetimagebuffer?language=objc) isn't an object, it's just a C structure, so it won't participate in reference counting. If you're going to pass it into a block that runs asynchronously, you need to ensure that that data remains valid. Notice that the documentation tells you specifically:

> *The caller does not own the returned buffer, and must retain it explicitly if the caller needs to maintain a reference to it.*

I haven't dug too far into it, but given the data type that probably means that you need to call [`CVBufferRetain()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1535810-cvbufferretain?language=objc) on `pixelBuffer` (and then `CVBufferRelease()` when you're done with it).